# How can I use jquery on a html document which has been loaded into another html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a heading.html file that is being loaded into my index.html.

heading.html

```
<header id="header">


 <div class="logo"></div>

 <nav>

  <a href="#home" class="slide-section">Home</a>
  <a href="#about-me" class="slide-section">About Me</a>
  <a href="#why-me" class="slide-section">Why Me?</a>
  <a href="#contact" class="slide-section">Contact</a>

</nav>

</header>
```

Then in my javascript file where I am loading in this file, it doesn't let me do any other functions.

functions.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $(function(){
    $("#includedHeader").load("/assets/_includes/header.html");
  });

  $(function(){
    $("#includedFooter").load("/assets/_includes/footer.html");
  });

  $(function(){
    $("#includedWhyme").load("/assets/_includes/why-me.html");
  });

  $(".slide-section").click(function(){
    alert('clicked');


  });

});
```

As you can see I'm trying to make a alert popup just to test if it is working but it doesn't.

Is there a way where I can still use other functions on these html files that are being loaded.

Comment: @mrlew, Will try now, I'm new to javascript so thanks for this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're binding the event like this `$(".slide-section").click()`, the element is not there yet. The `.load()` is still grabbing the contents from the server.

You can, however, use `on` method in the *document* (delegated events). It does a *live* event attachment (the event will be catched even if the element only exists in the future).

From the [.on() docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document.

Another suggestion (if I might) is to remove `$(function(){}` from around your `load` calls. `$(handler)` is a *shorthand* for [`$(document).ready(handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). So, as if you're calling it once, you don't need them anymore.

So, my suggestion would be something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#includedHeader").load("/assets/_includes/header.html");
    $("#includedFooter").load("/assets/_includes/footer.html");
    $("#includedWhyme").load("/assets/_includes/why-me.html");

});

$(document).on("click", ".slide-section", function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use directly click() method.. it would not work if the content is not already in the document..instead of this use .on() method to specifie click method its delegate have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.
so i from my point of view use following-

```
$(document).on("click", ".slide-section", function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```